# How do I read the file content and sent those content to the functions parameter

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file

I have one function ***ParseHtmlTable(string htmlContent)***.

Now in that function I want to pass the content of the html file. Now can I do by writing only filename with its path.Then I have to read that file.But I dont how to read this file ?

Then how to open particular file and read the contents of the file and send those contents to parameter of the function ?

***EDIT :***
System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path) can read all the html file but there is one file which I have it is not read through this function.What is the reason can be there ? And for that what can be the solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using

```
string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText( path );
```

[File.ReadAllText Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143368.aspx)

**EDIT to comment**

To itterate the files in a directory you can try using [Directory.GetFiles Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx)

```
foreach (string filename in Directory.GetFiles(path))
{
    //do what you need here
}
```

Comment: Rad up on the class System.IO.Directory.

Comment: I have not worked with **agilityPack** before, but I would personally not try parsing html with regex... http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: So there is no difference that we want to parse the html text or html table content in bot case we can use same parser ?

Comment: Sir..System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path) can read all the html file but there is one file which I have it is not read through this function.What is the reason can be there ? And for that what can be the solution ?